# Parameterized Queries /Without/ using queries

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, commerceserver2007

I've got a bit of a poor situation here. I'm stuck working with commerce server, which doesn't do a whole lot of sanitization/parameterization.

I'm trying to build up my queries to prevent SQL Injection, however some things like the searches / where clause on the search object need to be built up, and there's no parameterized interface.

Basically, I cannot parameterize, however I was hoping to be able to use the same engine to BUILD my query text if possible. Is there a way to do this, aside from writing my own parameterizing engine which will probably still not be as good as parameterized queries?

**Update: Example**

The where clause has to be built up as a sql query where clause essentially:

```
CatalogSearch search =  /// Create Search object from commerce server
search.WhereClause = string.Format("[cy_list_price] > {0} AND [Hide] is not NULL AND [DateOfIntroduction] BETWEEN '{1}' AND '{2}'", 12.99m, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), DateTime.Now);
```

*Above Example is how you refine the search, however we've done some testing, this string is **NOT SANITIZED**.

This is where my problem lies, because any of those inputs in the .Format could be user input, and while i can clean up my input from text-boxes easily, I'm going to miss edge cases, it's just the nature of things. I do not have the option here to use a parameterized query because Commerce Server has some insane backwards logic in how it handles the extensible set of fields (schema) & the free-text search words are pre-compiled somewhere. *This means I cannot go directly to the sql tables*

What i'd /love/ to see is something along the lines of:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[cy_list_price] > @MinPrice AND [DateOfIntroduction] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MinPrice", 12.99m);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", DateTime.Now);

CatalogSearch search = /// constructor
search.WhereClause = cmd.ToSqlString();
```

Comment: (it was a good idea to emphasise your scenario, and why you can't use parameters; thanks)

Comment: Can you give us an example of what/how you are trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you'll have to go old school and validate the data yourself before constructing the query. I'm not a .NET guy but in the CGI world I would sanitize the input with something like:

```
$foo =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9*%]//g
```

That will thwart any SQL injection I can think of and still allow wildcards. Only problem is the regexs are expensive.